# Why does View with ObservedObject in it, repeat multiple times when I have an active timer running

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a @Published Date() variable that I want to update every 5 seconds to keep app time in sync.\

I tired placing the timer inside the class, but that does not revolve the issue either.

video [preview videolink (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/_PvcHdyCH5E)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var countdown = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .current, in: .default).autoconnect()
    
    @ObservedObject var timer = globalTime()
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            Text("time \(timer.currentDate)")
            Text("This is a view")
            
        }
        .toolbar(content: {
            
            ToolbarItem(id: "help",placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ContentView2(),
                    label: {
                        Text("View Link")
                    })
            }
        })
        .onReceive(countdown, perform: { _ in
            timer.currentDate = timer.currentDate.addingTimeInterval(2)
            
        
        })
        
    }
}

class globalTime: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var currentDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 12)   
}
//NavigationLink View

struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var global = globalTime() 
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("This is a view")    
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of issues with your code. You need a `NavigationView` to be
able to use a `NavigationLink`. Also you need to pass the `timer` to your next View
`ContentView2` for it to be available in that view. The following code shows some
of these concepts.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let countdown = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .current, in: .default).autoconnect()
    
    @StateObject var timer = globalTime() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("time \(timer.currentDate)")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(id: "help", placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2(global: timer)) {
                        Text("View Link")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onReceive(countdown) { _ in
                timer.currentDate = timer.currentDate.addingTimeInterval(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

class globalTime: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 12)
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var global: globalTime  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("This is a view")
            Text("time \(global.currentDate)")  // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have a `Publisher` stored as a `@State` variable, which you shouldn't be doing. That timer is never modified and should be a `let` property, or bound to a `Published` variable, on your `ObservableObject`. Second, in `ContentView2` you have an observable object being set from inside the same view but `ObservableObject` means that that object's storage is handled externally, so by assigning the value where it's declared, you're violating the observable object contract. If you want to declare it inside your view, use `@StateObject`; `ObservableObject` is used when you pass view models down to children views. In that case, the parent is responsible for the view models storage so that when the child reloads, it doesn't also reload the view model.

I ran your code and I am not getting multiple navigation link pushes like your video shows. If you're still experiencing the issue, try a couple things:

- define your timer publisher on the observable object
- change `@ObservableObject` to `@StateObject`

Comment: The reason the timer is `@State` and not a let is so it isn't restarted when the `ContentView` gets reinit when something in the `App` struct changes because `@State` only inits the timer once.

Comment: @malhal it should not be `@State` under any circumstances. If it shouldn't be recreated, then it needs to be part of an observable object that gets injected into the content view.